# How to Drill down with flot charts

Tags: jquery, charts, flot

we're changing from highcharts to flot charts, and this is the first time I'm using flot charts, but I can't seem to find anything on getting a drill down effect with flot charts.

eg; if I have a bar chart and the user clicks on one of the bars, the chart goes to a more detailed view of that catagory.

Comment: should this help you out? http://www.cnblogs.com/scy251147/p/3399446.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to add the clickable option to the grid and then create your detailed view in the "plotclick" event. Similar to below:

example fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jSQ2Y/61/

```
var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ m1, m2, m3], {
xaxis : {
    mode          : "time",

    ticks: [1356998400000, 1359676800000, 1362096000000 ],
    timeformat: "%b"

},

grid:{
    clickable:true
    },

series : {
    bars: {
        show: true,


        fillColor : { colors : ["#32b9ff", "#2b78a0"] }
    }
}

});

$("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function(event, pos, item){
    alert(item.datapoint);
});
```

Comment: actually used this a short while after posting the question, but was too lazy to answer my own :D. thanks anyways. . .all I needed was the last three lines